# synthetic oil change frequency

Tags: oil, vw, jetta

2004 VW Jetta GLS:  always using full synthetic oil (Castro Edge 5w30) how often should the oil be changed? Can't find my manual or info online.

Comment: You can smell oil burning like when it gets low with synthetic you shouldn't have to change for 8 to 12 k. But its easy to start pushing it once u get there. If its real hot outside just add oil even mine will burn it on a hotcweek and never any other time

Comment: Thanks for your info. It's a 2004 vw jetta GLS with 148,000 miles. Has always had synthetic. Recently Walmart says change synthetic every 3,000 mi "because that's the way I've always done it" said the 60 yr old customer rep. I knew this wasn't correct but can't find 2004 jetta info online, so again thanks.

Comment: The only vehicles I've ever changed oil on such a regular frequency is race and rally cars.  For road cars 3000 miles is a very short distance.  I'd happily fill any of my cars with Castrol Edge that's already done 3000 miles, Edge is a great oil and will last far past that tiny mileage.

Comment: Thanks, Steve and all of you who have made suggestions on oil changes for the 2004 Jetta.  You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which engine you have, but following [this guideline](https://wiki.bentleypublishers.com/display/tech/Maintenance+Schedule+-+2004+-+Jetta,+Golf,+GTI,+Jetta+Wagon,+R32), you should do as follows:

```
Engine           Frequency
TDI              First @ 5k miles, then @ 10k, then every 10k miles
1.8T             Every 5k miles
2.0L             First @ 5k miles, then @ 10k, then every 10k miles
```

NOTE: I don't actually believe the 2.0L came in the 2004, just the TDI or 1.8T, but I could be wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on if your car is set for long life service intervals or not.  I've got the Bora 1.9 TDI PD130 (2004 model year) and it seems to need oil changes every 20k miles.

Checking the oil level regularly is very important as low oil on these engines will cause untold damage.  Also, if you change the oil more frequently than required then this is going to help, not hurt your engine.